# How install ocp-indent with git bash in windows 7

Tags: ocaml, windows-7-x64, opam

I have installed git bash with [this link](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and Ocaml with [this link](http://protz.github.io/ocaml-installer/) (click on the `Installer for 64-bit OCaml 4.02.3 + OPAM` button).

Then I have type `opam install ocp-indent` in git bash and see the result

```
The following actions will be performed:
  - install ocamlfind  1.8.0                                    [required by cmdliner, base-bytes, ocp-build]
  - install jbuilder   1.0+beta20                               [required by result]
  - install base-bytes base                                     [required by ocp-indent]
  - install result     1.3                                      [required by cmdliner]
  - install topkg      0.9.1                                    [required by cmdliner]
  - install cmdliner   1.0.2                                    [required by ocp-indent]
  - install ocp-build  1.99.20-beta                             [required by ocp-indent]
  - install ocp-indent 1.6.1
===== 8 to install =====
Do you want to continue ? [Y/n] Y

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[jbuilder: http] Command started
[ocp-build: http] Command started
[ocp-indent: http] Command started
[result: http] Command started
[ERROR] The sources of the following couldn't be obtained, aborting:
          - jbuilder.1.0+beta20
          - ocp-build.1.99.20-beta
          - ocp-indent.1.6.1
          - result.1.3
        (This might be due to outdated metadata, in this case run 'opam
        update')
```

I want to ask you if you have link that I can add with `opam repository` or a workaround (without cygwin) to install ocp-indent in Windows 7.

Thanks for your reading and your answers.

Comment: Have you tried running `opam update`?

Comment: yes of course it reponse to me ``Fatal error: exception Unix.Unix_error(20, "create_process", "cygcheck")``

Comment: I just noticed that you are on Windows. What flavor of installation do you use? Opam is not really supported on Windows, so it may be that you'll need to install your things manually.

Comment: I have written in my first message I use this installation http://protz.github.io/ocaml-installer/ `Installer for 64-bit OCaml 4.02.3 + OPAM`